# Disable Flash Player alert messages

Tags: flash

Is it possible to disable Flash Player alerts (eg. "A script in this movie is causing Mactromedia Flash Player 6 to run slowly.")? I'm not saying I want to do it: I only want to know if is it possible to disable them.   :-)

Comment: For the community: I found this useful PDF http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player_admin_guide/flash_player_admin_guide.pdf (but there's no mention of alerts disabling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to disable this altogether, but you can increase the amount of time before this is displayed, through your publishing settings in Flash Pro (if you are using Flash Pro), or a tool such as flasm. You might also be able to set it as an argument when compiling via flex.

Answer (score 0):

No i do not belie it is possible to disable these.  They are built in to the plugin and are not developer or user controllable.  Much like it's not possible to disable the "about flash player x.x" option in the context menu.